# Using Event Handlers for Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 20 items in a `List<myObject>`. Each has an instance of a `UserControl` associated with it. Each object is accessible via a `MenuStrip` that needs to display the UserControl when the appropriate item is clicked. Currently I have an event handler for each of them, which works, but I was wondering if a way exists to simplify this and use a single event handler for all of the items.

Is this possible? If so what is the best way to go about doing so.

EDIT:Can anybody else provide any input on this issue? I'm having trouble with Mailo's answer. Essentially all I need to do is make an event handler that can display the appropriate `UserControl` stored in a `List<myObject>` as a property when the correct MenuStrip item is clicked. Is there a more straightforward way to do this? Ideally I'd like to make it so that a `foreach` loop can go through the list and set up the handlers.

Is there nobody who can help me with this?

Comment: Are the separate handlers basically the same?  Could you have one and identify what's coming in and simply react differently, such as Switch-ing on what you know?  Perhaps leveraging the UserControl.Tag property?

Comment: Each handler essentially does the same thing. It just displays the appropriate UserControl.

Comment: I've also tried using the Tag property but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very difficult. First is you need some way to associate a menu item with a control in the list.

1) Since you have a list, index is simplest way ( you could use Dictionary<> to simplify this  association). So, lets say when you click the first menu item, you want `myObjecList[0]` to appear. When you click second MenuItem, `myObjectList[1]` would appear and so on. For this go to each menu item, and in the Properties, assign a value to `Tag` property. For first menu item, assign `Tag` to 0, for second item, assign `Tag` to 1 - and so on.

2) Create one event handler and assign the same handler to all menu items. The event handler could look something like this:

```
private void myToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // source menu item which was clicked
            ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

            if(item != null) 
            {
                int index = int.Parse(item.Tag.ToString()); // get the index from Tag
                myObject control = myObjectList[index];

                // do your stuff with your control

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the sender object to your event handler and check for the type inside the handler

it will be something like this

```
    //this will contain any properties you wanna send to the handler 
public class MyHandlerEventArgs : EventArgs
{

}

//this delegate gets the sender, you can change the sender type to be the encapsulated type of your controls
public delegate void MyHandler(object sender, MyHandlerEventArgs args);

//this is the class that fires the event in your case it will UI class I think
public class  MyController
{
    public event MyHandler myEvent;

    public void MyEvent_Fire()
    {
        if(myEvent != null)
            myEvent(this, new MyHandlerEventArgs());
    }
}

//here you can do your business logic for each control
public class MyAction
{
    MyController mc = new MyController();
    public MyAction()
    {
        mc.myEvent += new MyHandler(mc_myEvent);
    }

    void mc_myEvent(object sender, MyHandlerEventArgs args)
    {
        //check the sender type 
        //do your action
    }
}
```

this link might be useful to 
[check](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12043/Using-Events-and-Delegates-in-C)

Comment: Why not use `EventHandler<T>` instead defining a custom delegate, which basically has the same signature as the default delegate?

Comment: @marceln I missed this one, EventHandler<T> will be a better idea.
thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You might want the [`ItemClicked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked.aspx) event from the [`MenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx).  You can use the `ClickedItem` from the `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs`to find your `UserControl`

Some pseudocode:

```
// Initialize
myMenuStrip.ItemClicked += itemClickedEvent;

// ...
void itemClickedEvent(Object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
  int index = myObjectList.FindIndex(e => e.instanceOfUserControl == e.ClickedItem);
  // Now that we have the clicked item, display it how we would in an individual event handler.
  myObjectList[index].instanceOfUserControl.DoDisplay();
}
```

---

> Ideally I'd like to make it so that a foreach loop can go through the list and set up the handlers.

For this approach you'd use a `foreach` on the `List`

```
foreach (var listItem in myObjectList)
{
  listItem.TheEvent += myEventHandler;
}
```