# How do I find out which dynamically added menu item was clicked?

Tags: c#, menuitem

I created a dynamic menu using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    p = "a" + i;
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(p);
}
```

Now I want to know which one was clicked after creating it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem(v=vs.110).aspx) you have [ToolStripItem::Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

For example your code might look like:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      p = "a" + i;
      var item = new ToolStripItem(p); 
      item.Click += YOUR_HANDLER
      menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
   }
```

Comment: but it's not working for dynamically created menutoolstrip like i have used the loop to create 4 menus now i want to get the value of the clicked menu to use it later.                                        like can you explain a bit more

Comment: you define a single handler and in that handler check for SENDER object, which of menu items is.

Comment: look here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720618/using-event-handlers-for-multiple-objects